# SQL : Pivot way to query data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table as shown below. I want to query and show row data as columns

```
Customer  MetricName MetricValue    Date
 A          Upload    2          10-AUG-2007
 A          Download  2          10-AUG-2007
 A          Storage   100        10-AUG-2007
 A          Storage   110        11-AUG-2007
 B          Storage   200        11-AUG-2007
 A          Upload    2          12-AUG-2007
 A          Download  2          12-AUG-2007
 B          Upload    2          10-AUG-2007
 B          Download  2          10-AUG-2007
```

Usage Last Week

Download - sum of all downloads in a week
 Storage - Highest Value in the week

```
 Customer  Download  Upload   Storage
   A          4        4        110
   B          2        2        200
```

How to achieve this using Pivot or other method

Comment: what have you tried?  You can use a common table expression (or nested select) to filter the rows you want ane then use PIVOT

Comment: Is it just those 3 options - `Download`, `Upload` or `Storage`? - If so, you'd be better to just write the SQL directly.

Comment: If I use pivot how will i do 2 clauses - MAX and SUM on same column...?

Comment: Do the MAX with group by Week in a cte first and then use the PIVOT to do the sum

Comment: Can you please give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... `PIVOT` requires the same aggregate function to be applied all to columns; the old "manual" way of pivoting, using case expressions, is more flexible (as shown below). I wasn't sure what you meant by "week" - I just put that in a `WHERE` clause. Also, don't use reserved words like DATE for column (or table) names, you can't do it directly and you shouldn't do it the only possible way (using double quotes) - it's a very poor practice. I changed the column name `Date` to `dt`.

```
with 
     input_data ( customer, metricname, metricvalue, dt ) AS (
       select 'A', 'Upload'  ,  2   , to_date('10-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A', 'Download',  2   , to_date('10-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A', 'Storage' ,  100 , to_date('10-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A', 'Storage' ,  110 , to_date('11-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'B', 'Storage' ,  200 , to_date('11-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A', 'Upload'  ,  2   , to_date('12-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'A', 'Download',  2   , to_date('12-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'B', 'Upload'  ,  2   , to_date('10-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 'B', 'Download',  2   , to_date('10-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') from dual
     )
select   customer,
         sum( case when metricname = 'Upload'   then metricvalue end) as upload,
         sum( case when metricname = 'Download' then metricvalue end) as download,
         max( case when metricname = 'Storage'  then metricvalue end) as storage
from     input_data
where    dt between to_date('09-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy') and 
                                               to_date('15-AUG-2007', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
group by customer
order by customer
;

CUSTOMER     UPLOAD   DOWNLOAD    STORAGE
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A                 4          4        110
B                 2          2        200
```